# How can I deal with Indentation Error: unexpected indent?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, fuzzy-logic, mse

I am trying to Write the MSE function from Matlab to Python but I am getting this error:

```
 for i in range(len(RuleBase)):
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

This is my python code:

```
def Mse(RuleBase,x1,x2):
temp=np.zeros(shape = (1,6))
soogeno=np.zeros(shape = (49,4))

for i in range(len(RuleBase)):
    y=crisp(m=0,M=50,fy=RuleBase[i,3],n=7) 
    temp[0]=RuleBase[i]
    temp[0,2]=y
    Soogeno[i]=temp[0,0:3]
    return(soogeno)
```

Comment: Google how to write for loops and how to write function definitions in python. White-space is important, and your error is saying that you've indented (e.g. put a tab) somewhere where Python isn't expecting to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation is strictly enforced in python:

this should run:

```
def Mse(RuleBase,x1,x2):
    temp=np.zeros(shape = (1,6))
    soogeno=np.zeros(shape = (49,4))

    for i in range(len(RuleBase)):
        y=crisp(m=0,M=50,fy=RuleBase[i,3],n=7)
        temp[0]=RuleBase[i]
        temp[0,2]=y
        Soogeno[i]=temp[0,0:3]
    return(soogeno)
```

Comment: After any function definition def Mse() , if statement or for loop etc you you include 4 spaces on the next line () according to official python guidelines (PEP 8).